# WORD "ABCD" → "CADB"

Tags: word

I'm looking for as many words as possible to :
When you change the English word **"ABCD"** to **"CADB"**
Please find as many as you can.

I need your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a riddle.  It is also unclear on what you are looking for in case you're just asking a question

Comment: @Alex I think the request is to find words such that when the order of the letters change from ABCE to CADB it is still a valid word?

Comment: @HollyLeaves I thought of that too Holly but that is if "ABCD" and "CADB" are words, otherwise I dunno if it make sense.  Unless, Heypix is looking for All words that have this format.  Now it's not a puzzle, but 'puzzling'

Comment: "ABCD" is not a word? nor is "CADB"

Comment: If the condition is ABCD → DCBA, then there is WOLF → FLOW.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like a boring bruteforce to search for 4 lettered anagrams!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty answer thrown together with a little programming help.

I took a Scrabble word list from [this website](http://www.allscrabblewords.com/4-letter-words/) and then wrote a [simple bit of Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/wy4777tL/1/) to re-order the words and check if the new word is in the list.

A good chunk of these seem rather dubious at best, but you can always update the word list to something you prefer.

For people not understanding, we're looking for words such as

> IDLE

where if you label each letter from left-to-right as ABCD, then shuffle them into the order CADB, you get a new word (I've labeled them 1234 here for more clarity):

> IDLE
>  1234
>
>  3142
>  LIED

---

#### Here's the full list

> airn -> rani
>  alba -> baal
>  anna -> naan
>  anti -> tain
>  ashy -> hays
>  asps -> pass
>  ates -> east
>  ayes -> easy
>  clay -> acyl
>  deil -> idle
>  dyed -> eddy
>  east -> seta
>  edge -> geed
>  elhi -> heil
>  else -> seel
>  epha -> heap
>  eths -> hest
>  etna -> neat
>  eyer -> eery
>  gree -> eger
>  hare -> rhea
>  hyte -> they
>  idle -> lied
>  ikon -> oink
>  isba -> bias
>  isle -> lies
>  isms -> miss
>  lees -> else
>  naan -> anna
>  neat -> ante
>  noir -> inro
>  ohms -> mosh
>  onto -> toon
>  ordo -> door
>  orra -> roar
>  otto -> toot
>  peas -> apse
>  rede -> dree
>  rete -> tree
>  rood -> ordo
>  roti -> trio
>  seen -> esne
>  toot -> otto
>  wile -> lwei
>  yerk -> ryke

Comment: eddy, anna, do these count as they are names? I could easy come up with random names to make this work.

Comment: @TimBJames an `eddy` is a current. The website I got the word list from (which I linked in the main post) shows you definitions of any word in the list; apparently an `anna` is "a former copper coin of Pakistan and India" (although that's news to me!)

Comment: Not much of real interest, where both are commonly heard-of and used words, though I like the congruency of hare and rhea both being animals.